# What does enable=1 and priority=1 mean in ambari.repo?

Tags: repository, redhat-satellite

when I do `cat ambari.repo` I can see the last two rows showing
`enable=1` and `priority=1`. 
What is the meaning behind that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man yum.conf`

```
          enabled  Either  `1'  or  `0'. This tells yum whether or not use
          this repository.
```

and

```
          During depsolving, when choosing the
          best provider among several, yum will respect  the  priority  of
          each  provider's  repository  (note that there are other factors
          which yum considers, which may overweigh the  repository  prior-
          ity).  The  value  is  an integer from 1 to 99, 1 being the most
          preferred repository, and 99 being the least preferred  one.  By
          default all repositories have the priority of 80.
```

Comment: so for example if i had two cuda repisitories 9 and 10 if priority one is on cuda 9 , cuda 9 will be the first one to be called?

Comment: If two repositories have a package `foobar` in them then `yum install foobar` will pick the package that's in the priority repository (priority 9 beats priority 10).

Comment: tell me about the gpg check ?

Comment: This is all documented in `man yum.conf`...